# Is a quotient group of a non-cyclic group again a non-cyclic group?

Tags: group-theory, quotient-group

> Is a quotient group of a non-cyclic group again a non-cyclic group?

I know information about quotient groups of cyclic groups but don't know about non-cyclic

Comment: $G/G \cong \{e\}$ is always cyclic.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  Also, consider $S_3/A_3$

Comment: With this kind of question the first thing to do is to simply try some examples. As the smallest non-cyclic group is non-simple, it is *guaranteed* to work!

Comment: After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark $\checkmark$ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/), [What should I do if someone answers my question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 2):

No.

Consider the Klein four group $$\langle a,b\mid a^2, b^2, ab=ba\rangle$$ and quotient out by the normal subgroup generated by $a$; that is, "kill $a$".

Answer (score 1):

A `metacyclic` group $G$  is precisely an extension of a cyclic group $Q$ by a normal cyclic subgroup $N$, i.e. if there exists a short exact sequence
$$1\rightarrow N \hookrightarrow G\twoheadrightarrow Q\to 1.$$
Such groups are not necessarily cyclic, nor even abelian.

For instance $S_3$ is metacyclic since its quotient by the subgroup generated by a $3$-cycle is cyclic. Dihedral groups are metacyclic too.